# How do you read a file into a dictionary with its key as the words length, and the values as the words with that length

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my code, I need to read a file and put it into a dictionary with lists. for example, if file.txt consisted of:

```
cat
dog
as
mars
hello
```

I would need to format it into `{2 : ["as"], 3 : ["cat", "dog"], 4 : ["mars"], 5 : ["hello"]}`

Heres what I've tried so far

```
dictionary = {}
file = open(dictionary_file, "r")
for line in file:
    x = line
    b = len(line)-1
    x = line[0:b]
    dictionary[b].append(x)
```

Comment: also this looks similar, though I've only glanced at it: [Returning Dictionary-length of words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35986285/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        key = len(line)
        if not key in d:
            d[key] = []
        d[key].append(line)
print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item:item[0]))
```